# trying to run my flask web and post the data to firebase but I seem to have an issue with pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxhC4.png)

Here is the error I'm receiving

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you mean you cannot import the module?

Comment: I have imported the pyrebase package but it still gives out the error that there is no module named crypto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deleted the from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA in the pyrebase.py and the error disappeared